# the release date for next safari

Tags: javascript, browser, safari, browser-support

Where can I find a schedule for the safari release date and the features that will be included?
I have found this https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=Safari, I can see there only one version ahead.
Is there something similar what chrome has: https://www.chromestatus.com/features/schedule
Or firefox has: https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2019/09/17/moving-firefox-to-a-faster-4-week-release-cycle/

Answer (score 0):

Apple usually releases one major version (14, 15…) per year and one or two minors between each major (e.g. 15.1, 15.2).

- Major versions are in September and October (often a couple of days or weeks near iOS major release).
- Minor versions are usually in March, but sometimes we get one before (we got 15.1 in October, 15.2 in December and hopefully.

There’s no way to know when the next major or minor version (it’ll likely be 15.4) will land. They don’t have a fixed cycle (unlike [Chrome](https://chromestatus.com/roadmap) and [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases)). But when it lands, the release notes are almost simultaneously published on [Webkit blog](https://webkit.org/blog/) and on the official [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes) page.

If you want the dates for previous versions, the browser selector of [Can I Stop](https://canistop.net/b/safari/15.2) has most of them (disclaimer: I maintain that small app).

You can also have a look at the [Webkit Status](https://webkit.org/status/) for a list of in-development features and at [Safari STP (Safari Tech Preview) release notes](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/release-notes/) to learn more about ongoing development in Safari. I also maintain a list of main browsers “status platform” on [Can We](https://canwe.dev/#sites-platform-status).